# JPA Criteria API Specification JOIN by condition and result isn't null

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The code example:

```
@Entity
public class Event {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String name;
@OneToMany(...)
private List<Actions> actions;

}


@Entity
public class Action {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String name;
private Date date;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
private Event event;

}

public class EventSpecification {

public static Specification<Event> findByCriteria(EventSearchCriteria criteria) {

    return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        criteria.getEventName().ifPresent(name ->
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get(Event_.name)), name)));

        criteria.getDate().ifPresent(date -> 
        // Need one more Predicat - event.has.actions.with.date.equals.criteria.date
        );

        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    };
}
}
```

**The question is:**

How to create the Predicate - only Events which have Actions with Action.date = searchCriteria.date. I think it's possible but I can't find a solution.

Comment: There is no such thing as "JPA Specification". There is "JPA Criteria API". There is "Spring Data JPA". "Specification" is not part of the JPA API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe that will help you pointing out the right way

```
criteria.getDate().ifPresent(date -> {
     Join join = root.join("actions");
     predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("date"), date);
});
```